# How to slide a string in python?

Tags: python, slide

I want to slide a string but the program output is an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<tmp 3>", line 28, in <module>
    print_hell(sentence)
  File "<tmp 3>", line 23, in print_hell
    print(i)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What should I do?

'''

```
sentence = "hello, how are you doing. I am doing good how are you. the work I am doing is hellish. please help me escape this hell. I will try my best. But oh hell no. this is too hard"

def string2list(text):
    ''' devide the list into smaller interval for easy to work '''
    final_text = []
    k = text.split(".")
    
    for i in range(len(k)):
        v = k[i].split()
        final_text.append(v)
    # return something like this [["",""],["",""]]
    return final_text


def print_hell(text):
    "print the sentence with the word 'hell', even the word like 'hello' with hell in it "
    khn = string2list(text)
    for i in range(len(khn)):
        for l in range(len(khn[i])):
            for c in range(len(khn[i][l])-4):
                # 4 because the word hell has 4 
                if khn[i][l][c:4] == "hell":
                    print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #print(string2list(text))
    print_hell(sentence)
    # v = string2list(text)
    # print(text[1][2])
```

'''

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
essay = "print the sentence with the word 'hell'. Even the word like 'hello' with hell in it. And even hellooo. Not this though "
list_of_sentences = essay.split(".")
for sentence in list_of_sentences:
    if "hell" in sentence.lower():
        print(sentence)
```

This way you first convert the essay to a list of sentences and then check every sentence in the list if the combination of letters "hell" is in it

Comment: but that would not print the sentence containing the word 'hello' will it (the world hello also have "hell" in it. I want to write this for even a big essay, not just a few sentences.

Comment: Actually, try it, it will print 'hello' if you pass it.

Comment: Try it, and if it works please accept my answer as correct

Comment: it still says "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" on the print line

Comment: I just tested it again, it works for me... you didn't change anything?

Comment: Open a new file or IDLE and try it on its own

Comment: I didn't change a thing. I still don't understand what that error means +1

Comment: I copied and pasted my code and worked, I copied and pasted the code you posted, i doesn't give me any error, just doesn't return what you want

Comment: That's weird. IDK why that happened. LOL. I will try something different. I don't even understand what that error means. DID you import anything? or what version of python or anaconda you are using

Comment: I use python 3.8 on Pycharm.and didn't import anything

Comment: To reverse a list into a string you do "".join(list)